# Tense of "I see a black bird."

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, present-tense

> I see a black bird.

Is it present indefinite tense or present continous tense?

Comment: It isn't whether the action referred to is ongoing, but whether the verb form is inflected to show the ongoing nature of the action.  Water drips from the eaves.  Water is dripping from the eaves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a *present indefinite* tense, or as is it more commonly named: the *simple present*/*present simple*.

The present continuous form would be:

> I **am seeing** a black bird.

The present continuous tense is formed using a conjugated form of *to be* followed by an *ing-form* of your main verb:

> - I **am** *running*.
> - She **is** *sleeping*.
> - We **are** *partying*.

However, the continuous form does not really work here. With the verb *to see*, the present continuous form is often understood as 'to frequent the company of', such as dating someone for example:

> I am seeing a girl at the moment, she is so cute!

Comment: Sir, do you agree with this lengthy comment? According to the meaning it's "Present Continuous Tense".
Though the structure is like Present Indefinite Tense, it can't be "Present Indefinite Tense",its meaning will be "I always see a black bird" which is impossible.
Though the structure of Present continuous tense  is " sub+am/ is/ are + verb + ing" some verbs like see, love, hate, belong, get, etc don't take "ing". That's why the structure will be like  Present Indefinite Tense.
Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, **verbs of perception** normally do not take a continuous form. If you have a look at this page, under 'verbs that are not usually used in the continuous form', you will find more information: http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-continuous-tense/

Comment: I do occasionally hear the present continuous used this way, in AmE informal speech, especially in the negative.  Alice: "Bob, would you get the flour from the cupboard?"  Bob, looking into the cupboard: "Hmm, I'm not seeing any flour here."  But I don't think this would be considered correct in formal speech or writing.

Comment: Please tell me its meaning.